# [METEOR $addToSet]Cannot insert into object '$addToSet' is empty

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update an array inside object in Meteor using $addToSet, but I am receiving an error.

The object looks like this:

```
{   
    ...  
    profile: {  
        photos: [] 
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
Images.insert(files[i], function (err, fileObj) {
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.user()._id, {
        $addToSet: {
            'profile.photos': {
                created_at: new Date(),
                image: "dd",
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I get this error:

```
 MongoError: '$addToSet' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$mod: {<field>: ...}}
```

I have tried different operators and syntax, but it has not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like you didnt add field profile.photos at register.
You do it with method
`Accounts.onCreateUser`
It looks like this

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
  user.profile:{
  photos:[]
  }
})
```

Here are docs
http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/

Comment: I also forgot to change my Simple Schema ^^.. Thanks for your help anyway, Happy new year !